# Getting, processing and deleting all queue messages instead of doing one by one?

Tags: c#, azure

I am working on Azure queue. I need to get, process and delete all queue messages. What I am doing right now is calling the GetMessage, process the message and calling DeleteMessage one by one.

```
var message = _queue.GetMessage();
if (message == null)
{
     return;
}
// processs
 _queue.DeleteMessage(message);
```

Is there is a way to get all messages first then process it and delete all these processed messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get all messages from a queue in a single call. `Maximum number of messages you can Get from a queue in a single call is 32`. So what you would need to do is something like:

```
var messages = _queue.GetMessages(32);
```

and then process these messages instead of getting one message at a time.

**UPDATE**

So a few things based on your comments:

- A queue has a property called [`ApproximateMessages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.approximatemessagecount.aspx) which will tell you approximately how many messages are there in the queue. This should give you an idea about the total number of messages.
- You can't delete 32 messages in one shot. You will need to delete one message at a time.

Based on these, do take a look at pseudo code below:

```
            do
            {
                var messages = _queue.GetMessages(32);
                foreach (var msg in messages)
                {
                    ProcessMessage(msg);
                    DeleteMessage(msg);
                }
                var approximateMessagesCount = _queue.FetchAttributes().ApproximateMessageCount.Value;
                if (approximateMessagesCount == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            } while (true);
```

Basically you have to keep on fetching messages from the queue (32 at a time), process individual message and once the message is processed then delete it. Once these 32 messages have been processed and deleted, you have to check if there are any more messages in the queue. If there are messages, you would repeat this process. If there are no messages, then you would exit out of the loop.

Comment: I am not certain how many messages in a queue. Can you show an example to get all messages(using _queue.GetMessages in a batch of 32)  and process and delete? Can we delete 32 messages at a time?

Comment: Updated my answer. HTH.

Comment: Nice and Thanks. But there is still problem we need to fix. What if the app continuously queuing. Means the while loop will run until app stop queuing. MaximumMessagesToProcessPerBatch may work here.

Comment: I think it will be better if you check messages.Count() instead of ApproximateMessageCount because already have messages object. No?

Comment: I would agree with your comments. The code was just a pseudo code to explain how you could fetch and process all messages from a queue. Typically you would want to distribute the message processing across multiple nodes where each node process a finite amount of messages.

Comment: Regarding your comment about checking messages.Count(), I don't think that would work because it will only tell you the number of messages fetched. It will not tell you how many messages are there in the queue.